# PowerQuery: Sorting a dynamic number of columns alphanumerically

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

So I've got a Power Query script that at one point pivots a table.

This creates a dynamic number of columns.

One of these columns is text, but will usually have a value at the front such as `1. this is a description` `2. this is another description` etc, up to `34. this is a description`.

PowerQuery is sorting these columns alphabetically left to right. However, I would like to sort them by number.

As the number of columns is variable, as are the column names, I cannot Reorder by the explicit column names.

I'm a bit stuck here, so any help would do!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that PowerQuery will put the pivoted column names in the order that they appear in the column that they are pivoted from, so if you get them sorted how you like before pivoting, then you should get the column order you want.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the case - I created a numeric column using the system here https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/11/19/keep-only-numbers-in-power-query/

However, even after sorting on this new, numerical column, the pivot did not create the columns in the appropriate order.

Comment: @Stu-co Hmm. That's how it seems to be working in my version of Power BI desktop so I'm having trouble replicating what you are describing. Can you link to a .pbix that is doing what you are describing?

Comment: Interesting. It may be because I am using Power Query in Excel, and so I am probably running a few versions behind. I will look at getting an example data set and power query code for you soon.

Comment: @Stu-co can you link to an Excel file that behaves as you describe?

Comment: Strangely, when I remove the data in the step just before and move it to a new Excel file, apply the pivot again, it displays the behaviour you are describing!

Comment: I cannot link to the exact file as it has client data in it.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/exampledata Here is a link to the data from the step before copied out, and with the same pivot applied.

However, when doing this in the live process, the behaviour is different.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/exampledata_1 Now with the actual output for comparison. The pivot line itself is identical.

Comment: @Stu-co When you do this, do you make sure that when you do your sort that the TransactionId column you are sorting is defined as a numeric type? I tried sorting it descending and it didn't work right until I switched that field to an integer.

Comment: No, I can't do that as I cannot guarantee that that TransactionId is numeric. It is unfortunately coming from my client's information systems so I have no control over datatype.

What I am doing is extracting the non numeric values from it using a Text.Remove(), sorting on that new column, then deleting that column.